# VLC Media player won't play video when I add subtitles

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I am currently trying to play a video file on VLC Media Player. The video file is from an episode of a TV show, and it doesn't come with subtitles. When I play the video on VLC Media Player by simply opening File Explorer and clicking on the file in the front page Quick Access menu, the video plays with no error whatsoever. However, I am trying to add a subtitle .srt file to the video. When I try adding the subtitle file to the video, the entire thing stops working, even if I disable the subtitle again.
If I delete my subtitle file, the video plays properly, but I want to keep the subtitles.
For my issue, I get this result:
[VLC Media Player not playing video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrx6b.png).
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just for comparison try MPC-HC, https://www.fosshub.com/MPC-HC.html . Also, be sure both subtitle and video files have same filename (with differing extension) and are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what good this'll do to you now but this is what worked from me:

- Open VLC Media Player
- Click on Media
- Click on Convert/Save
- Add the file you're having trouble with
- Press Convert/Save
- In Profile, select mp4
- Select the destination folder
- Press Start

The file should work properly after that. It has to do something with the format of the file not being mp4 or mkv.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, actually the thing is that the video you are playing is in (ts or mp4 MPEG) codec u can also check this from (tools-media information-codec) in VLC,i searched everywhere but currently there is no solution for this as the VLC doesn't support any format of subtitles with MPEG videos. so u just have to download POT player it will work 100% .this is only solution i know.Hope it helps